# Optimizely acount singup

Tags: optimizely

Here i am trying to create new account on optimizley but i unable to do that i also download optimizely windows version now i did find any signup button .. how i signup with optitmizley .. i search but never found any better solutions . will anyone please guide me .  i want to create A/B testing on optimizely

i created account with ROLLOUTS but here i did not any option for A/B testing check image

[image]
any solutions ?

this is the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an account to create A/B tests with Optimizely, you'll have to contact sales via the plans page https://www.optimizely.com/plans/ or the contact page https://www.optimizely.com/contact/ because Optimizely Web and Optimizely Full Stack are enterprise software solutions requiring sales contracts.

Optimizely Rollouts; however, is a free product providing unlimited feature flags and feature rollouts for development teams. Optimizely Rollouts does not provide A/B testing functionality.

Hope this helps!